# Python: reading from two separate lines, creating two lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am reading from a txt file: (it is formatted exactly like below)

> (+1 +2 +3 +4)
>
> (-4 -9)(-3 -6 -7)

My desired output is to have two (integer) lists

Both BEFORE the     ***\n***     and AFTER.

Example:

```
BEFORE_LIST = [1,2,3,4] 

AFTER_LIST = [[-4,-9] , [-3, -6, -7]]
```

I can not figure out the correct combination of splits and strips to make this happen.

Any help I am very grateful.

Comment: Can your file contains nested lists ?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am beginner with python, I am not familiar with nested lists. but there is no rule saying it can not be used. please explain if you have time.

Comment: Is `+1 +2 +3 +4` valid input? If yes what's the expected output?

Comment: A nested list is just a list containing more lists so `a_list = [[*], [*]]` would be a nested list as one example. I think @user312016 meant if your file can contain things like this `((-4 -9)(-3 -6 -7))` which would be the equivalent of a nested list using your file structure

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am not sure if nested lists would work, because the elements on each line has to be separate.  It's like each line in the file must be a separate list. After the \n is read , it creates another new list.

Comment: Does your file contain only two lines? and your requirement is to produce two lists BEFORE_LIST and AFTER_LIST?

Comment: I am very embarrassed but I believe I figured out a potential answer. Because I will know EXACTLY how many lines are in my text file, I can read each individually.

Comment: Yes, BEFORE_LIST = readline() became line 0, and AFTER_LIST = readline() became line 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
listOfValues = (x.split(' ')for x in (val.replace(')','') for val in input().split('(')))
listOfIntegers = list(filter(None, [[int(value) for value in values if isInt(value)]for values in listOfValues]))

print(listOfIntegers)
```

The is `isInt` method can be defined as:

```
def isInt(s):
    try:
        int(s)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Or a more elaborate solution that avoids the exception:

```
def isInt(s):
    return s.replace('+').replace('-').isdecimal() // doesn't cover all cases
```

This doesn't checks for invalid input format (For eg unmatched paranthesis).

Comment: Instead of your custom `isInt` function, what about simply using `str.isdecimal()`?

Comment: @ByteCommander edited. Although isDecimal doesn't takes care of preceding +/- in the string and so I had to special case for that. I kind of liked my IsInt method more although it involved exceptions in happy paths which kind of made me wary of perf. Obviously both custom isInt and isDecimal can be avoided by using some regex magic.

Comment: Right. You could leave your old version as alternative, just show both of them in your answer. My comment was just a suggestion, the try-catch approach was also okay. But it would be nice if you could format your code in a way that we don#'t have to use the horizontal scrollbar... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Will it do?

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval
with open('test','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace(' ',',').replace('+','')
        my_list = re.findall(r'\(.+?\)',line)
        result = [list(literal_eval(i)) for i in my_list]
        if len(result)==1:
            result = [i for term in result for i in term ]

        print result
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[[-4, -9], [-3, -6, -7]]
```